# XSD: Validate a subnode based on its name and accept everything below

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation

In an XML file, I've one specific node that I want to be present, but not validate any of its content(sub-elements & attributes).

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<RootContainer  xmlns="MyNamespace">
    <ElementA/>
    <ElementB/>
    <ElementC/>
    <OtherElement SomeAttribute="Value">
        <SubElementX/>
        <SubElementY/>
    </OtherElement>
</RootContainer>
```

**XSD use to validate**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xs:schema  targetNamespace="MyNamespace"
            elementFormDefault="qualified"
            xmlns="MyNamespace"
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="RootContainer">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name ="ElementA"/>
                <xs:element name ="ElementB"/>
                <xs:element name ="ElementC"/>
                <xs:element name="OtherElement" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" >
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:anyAttribute/>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

But I get several errors (With .Net, also with Notepad++(with the Xml plugin) ):
Validation of current file using XML schema:

**Notepad++ Errors:**

```
ERROR: Element '{MyNamespace}OtherElement', attribute 'SomeAttribute': No matching global attribute declaration available, but demanded by the strict wildcard. 
ERROR: Element '{MyNamespace}SubElementX': No matching global element declaration available, but demanded by the strict wildcard. 
ERROR: Element '{MyNamespace}SubElementY': No matching global element declaration available, but demanded by the strict
```

**.Net errors:**

```
The 'SomeAttribute' attribute is not declared.
The 'MyNamespace:SubElementX' element is not declared.
The 'MyNamespace:SubElementY' element is not declared.
```

So why? Did I misunderstood the `xs:any` and `xs:anyAttribute`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the anyType for that:

```
<xs:element name="OtherElement" type="xs:anyType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
```

Comment: Seems nice and good, but by curiosity, apart it's not as clean/elegant, what is the reason the other version didn't work?

Comment: I believe that the `<xs:any>` and `<xs:anyAttribute>` are used to specify that it is allowed to use any element/attribute, but that element/attribute still has to be defined by another XSD.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Weird that  `xs:anyType` don't have the same behavior then ;)

Comment: @cvesters Your approach is also correct, but you probably need an attribute `processContents="skip"` in both your `xs:any` and `xs:anyAttribute` . This makes your XML processor not to try to validate the any content or annyAttribute.